# StackEdit Icons

Tags: html, css, fonts, stackedit

I recently came across a webapp called [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/#) which lets you create HTML documents while typing in (almost) plain text, using the Markdown syntax (that is also implemented here on StackExchange) to convert text to HTML. The introductory document has certain icon codes like `<i class='icon-upload'></i>` which generates (I assume) HTML icons.

**Does anyone know where I can find a list**(exhaustive would be very good) of icon codes for various purposes? Apparently, going by the credits in the 'About' section, it implements this using something called [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons) but the codes listed there don't seem to work in StackEdit. Maybe it implements some code but has it's own list of icon codes. Any help?

Comment: Looks like they use [fontello](http://fontello.com/), which allows you to create a custom icon set with custom names.  If StackEdit doesn't document what icons are available, they may not be intended for use.  You could read their CSS to see what icons are available.

Comment: Yeah maybe. The icons were never listed like `You can use "foo" to do "bar"` like the other features. Reading the css might help though.

Comment: I am crossposting to [webapps.se] it might be more on topic there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://stackedit.io/res/libs/fontello/demo.html

(I'm the developer of StackEdit)

Comment: thanks man :D where can I contact in you case I run into problems/have queries?

Comment: also is it possible for me to add icons from any other style sheet? for instance, the font awesome ones?

Comment: The best place to reach me is on the [GitHub's project page](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/). See [this thread](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/137) about custom extension and theming. It must be possible to inject the `font-awesome.css` with javascript (see comment from KyleMit).

Comment: @Sabyasachi - I'm glad you like my answer, but this is the answer I would want to find if I were searching for this information.  You should accept this answer.

Comment: @gilly3 done. I accepted your answer for the 'sass'. Although you're right. If a google search led me to this page, I'd prefer to have this at as the first result.

Comment: @benweet I am sorry, but can you please take a look at the question related to [stackedit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23051541/1090562)

Comment: @benweet, How would we do right alignment using StackEdit?

Comment: The list given is extensive, but it doesn't show which/what to include in the head section to get these working on another site. You need to include something related to "fontello", and not "Font Awesome", but what to include/inject that is a mystery

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [non-authoritative list](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!provider=gist&gistId=52155de3575795ebb3ef&filename=StackEditIcons) I created by scraping the CSS.  I ran this script in the JavaScript console while StackEdit was open to get the list:

```
var classes = {};
[].forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(ss){
    [].forEach.call(ss.cssRules, function(r) {
        if (r.selectorText) {
            r.selectorText.split(/,\s*/).forEach(function(sel){
                if (/^\.(icon-[a-z\d-]+)/i.test(sel)) {
                    classes[RegExp.$1] = null;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
var classList = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classes);
```

Comment: If I asked [webapps.se] someone would give me a list because they knew the list. Now **this** is what SO does. I like this. I like this very much.