# How can I use stackedit's markdown editor in my application

Tags: markdown, wysiwyg, stackedit

I am looking for a way to integrate stackedit's markdown editor into my own project and I can not find a way to do this. I looked into [stackedit's github page](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit) and I am stuck.

I see how can I edit nicely already precreated document, but I want to integrate it in the similar way how can I add [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) or any other editor. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

StackEdit is not embeddable. PageDown is.

See https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/150

And eventually https://github.com/jmcmanus/pagedown-extra/issues/27

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887)  and add enough detail to your answer to make it not completely reliant on an external link. How about explaining what the links are, and how they're relevant?  Maybe copy and paste a helpful quote from each?

Comment: Why does **stackedit** have a git page, if you cant use the code for your own app?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [stackedit's github](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit). Benweet has created [an embeddable mardown editor](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit.js). It is this repo that you must check to use their editor in your web app.